# Inequality for quartic polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I have the following inequality: $\alpha x<1+\beta x^4$ and this equality should hold for all $x \geq 0$ and some $\alpha,\beta \geq 0$ to be determined ($\alpha,x,\beta$ should all be real). I am considering the pairs $(\alpha,\beta)$ for which this holds given that it must be true for all $x \geq 0$.

For $\alpha=0$ I find $\beta \geq 0$ but for $\alpha>0$ I got stuck. Wolfram Alpha tells me that $\beta>27\alpha^4/(256)$ should hold. I guess this is related to the discriminant of the above polynomial $\beta x^4 +1 - \alpha x$ which is also precisely giving the above condition. But I don't see why this condition suffices?

Comment: Find $\alpha$, such as $\alpha x$ is a tangent to $1 + \beta x^4$.

Comment: @user58697 . The derivative of $\alpha x$ is constant, it is just $\alpha$, but the derivative of $1+\beta x^4$ is $4x^3 \beta$. But these cannot be equal for all $x \geq 0$ right?

Comment: To be a tangent, it must have $x$ such that $\alpha x = 1 + \beta x^4$ (as well as $\alpha = 4\beta x^3$). Now exclude $x$, and obtain a relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x \gt 0$ the inequality is equivalent to $\beta x^3 + \frac{1}{x} \ge \alpha$. By AM-GM, the LHS:

$$
\require{cancel}
\beta x^3 + \frac{1}{x} = \beta x^3 + \frac{1}{3x} + \frac{1}{3x} + \frac{1}{3x} \ge 4 \sqrt[4]{\beta \cancel{x^3} \frac{1}{3^3 \cancel{x^3}}}
$$

The minimum is attained when $\beta x^3 = \frac{1}{3x}$, so the condition for the inequality to hold for all $x \gt 0$:

$$
\alpha \lt 4 \sqrt[4]{\beta \cdot \frac{1}{3^3}} \;\;\;\;\iff\;\;\;\; \alpha^4 \lt 256 \cdot \frac{\beta}{27}
$$

Comment: What is meant with AM-GM?

Comment: @Mathphysmeister [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) is the inequality between the arithmetic and geometric means.